# SQL Remove Unicode characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unicode

Input :

> “This is an example”. “Test Method”

Desired Output:

> This is an example. Test Method

I tried using replace method to find and replace these characters but still not able to strip them out. Learnt that both `“`, `”` are Unicode characters and are different from standard quotes i.e. `"`.

```
Select
REPLACE(REPLACE(some_text, '“',''),'”','') as DerivedText
from Table
```

Comment: FWIW, Unicode constants look like `N'“'` not `'“'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both work fine (although only second is correct for unicode):

```
--1
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(1000) = '“This is an example”. “Test Method”'

PRINT REPLACE(REPLACE(@s, '“', ''), '”', '')
GO
--2
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(1000) = N'“This is an example”. “Test Method”'

PRINT REPLACE(REPLACE(@s, N'“', N''), N'”', N'')
GO
```

> This is an example. Test Method
>
> This is an example. Test Method

Examine your data.

Comment: Thanks that worked. So looks like the trick was to cast the string to varchar or nvarchar before doing replace, once i did this, i was able to omit these characters.